# How to query a table that I don't own and don't have bigquery.jobs.create permissions on it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-nodejs-client

I was shared on a BigQuery table that I don't own and I don't have the `bigquery.jobs.create` permission on the dataset that contains the table.
I successfully listed all the tables in the dataset, but when I tried to query the table using this code:

```js
tables.map(async (table) => {
        const url = `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${process.env.PROJECT_ID}/queries`;
        const query = `SELECT * FROM \`${table.id}\` LIMIT 10`;
        const data = {
          query,
          maxResults: 10,
        };
        const reqRes = await oAuth2Client.request({
          method: "POST",
          url,
          data,
        });
        console.log(reqRes.data);
      });
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Access Denied: Project project_id: <project_id>
gaia_id: <gaia_id>
: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project <project_id>.
```

I can't ask for those permissions, what should I do in this situation?

**IMPORTANT:**
I have tried to run the same query in the GCP and it ran successfully, but it seems like it **created a temporary table clone** and then queried this table and no the original one:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to access data that "I can't ask for those permissions"? The answer is to get the correct permissions.

Comment: @JohnHanley - This is a part of an exercise... I wouldn't ask if that was the solution I was searching for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two projects here: your project, and the project that contains the table.

You currently create the job in ${process.env.PROJECT_ID} that you use in URL, try specifying your own project instead, where you can create jobs.

You'll need to modify query to include table's project to allow BigQuery to find it, so make sure ${table.id} includes project (table's - not yours), dataset and table.

Comment: Yep, that worked... I got lost in the documentation
Thanks a lot, man. If you don't mind, I had a different question that you might be able to help with:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257742/how-to-connect-to-google-bigquery-metadatalookupwarning-error-nodejs

I tried to connect through their client and I don't know how to initialize the BigQuery client with the necessary permissions, it throws an error... it would be much easier for me If I could query the DB without having to explicitly sending requests to the REST API.